# How to call macros using azure api

Tags: excel, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

I have an excel file containing around 100K rows in onedrive. This file contains some macros. I want to run these macros using api.I want to pass these macro functions as parameters.

For example

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/root:/book1.xlsx:/workbook/tables/{id|name}

Here, I want to call macros function in place tables/{id|name}

Any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you can only run a macro in an Excel file open in an actual Excel instance. So you cannot run a macro unless you open the file in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to run an Excel macro, you need a running Excel instance that opens the file containing the macro and runs the code. There is no way around this I'm afraid.

So you need a machine - physical or virtual - where Excel is installed. Then you can have a script open the Excel file there and run the macros.

If you are working in a cloud environment or on a web server for example, you would be better off rewriting the code in another language, independent of Excel. (Trust me, I've been there, done that.)

Comment: Can you share a document to do that?

Comment: A document to do what? Rewrite the code in another language? There is no easy way... I used C# and [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), but take your pick.